# prettier overwrites eslint array-bracket-spacing rule

Tags: eslint, prettier

ESlint **adds** spaces inside array brackets, prettier **removes** them.

I use vscodium with ESLint and Prettier extensions. I run the command in package.json:

```json
{
  "lint": "eslint --fix ./index.js && prettier --write ./index.js"
}
```

.eslint.json:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "always"] // the rule
  }
}
```

index.js:

```js
const myTestFunction = () => {
  const [num1] = [1, 3]; // the error
//const [ num1 ] = [ 1, 3 ]; // expected

  return console.log(num1);
};
myTestFunction();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved that inside my CRA project by:

1. [Install Create React App with Typescript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/)

   `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
2. ESLint is already in CRA, no need to
   [install it](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started).

   Initialize it - `npm init @eslint/config`
3. [Install Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html)

   `npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier`

   - Integrate it into eslint (I prefer
     [standard way](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html)) -
     https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#installation

     `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier`
   - Configure *.eslintrc.json*
4. Install Airbnb ESLint configs. It is
   [made for JS](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js#L139).

   Install
   [*eslint-config-airbnb-typescript*](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript)
   to bind it with typescript.
   `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb-typescript`

   - Configure *.eslintrc.json*
   - Some rules are not clear for me now, so I look up and escape them.

     For example
     [*jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control*](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/302#issuecomment-425512505)

   ```json
   "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [ "error", {
        "required": {
          "some": [ "nesting", "id"  ]
        }
      }],
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ "error", {
        "required": {
          "some": [ "nesting", "id"  ]
        }
      }]
    }
   ```
5. Add scripts to *package.json*

```json
{
  "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  "lint": "eslint --fix src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  "test": "npm run format && npm run lint"
}
```

6. Profit!!! No more packages or settings are required.